# select2 multiple tags placeholder style changes after focused/interacted with?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Hey this issue is with the select2 boxes and I've localized the issue to this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/c08dap2L/1/

1. Look at the box on load in
2. Add and delete an item
3. Look at the box after

Observe that the margin-left is now missing.

What is causing this?  What do I have to change about this fiddle so that the placeholder text does not collapse to the left after interacted with?

html

```
<select id="tags" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Kerry">Kerry</option>
    <option value="Cork">Cork</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$('#tags').select2({
    placeholder: "Add your tags here",
});
```

css

```
#tags {
    width:100%
}
/* Overrides the text wrapper inside of the input box */
li[class="select2-search select2-search--inline"] {
    margin-left:15px;
}
```